# Swift array instances in Memory

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

Now i’m watching WWDC, Understanding Swift performance session

In that session one picture makes me confusing

[image]

I know that array cannot determine it’s size at compile time, so they store item instance in heap, and store that item’s reference in stack like above (`d[0]`, `d[1]`)

but what is `refCount` in that array(next to `d[0]`)?

Is`drawables` variable pointer for array instance?

Comment: “ so they store item instance in heap, and store that item’s reference in stack like above (d[0], d[1])” not true. Yes, the items are stored in existential containers on the heap (since this is an array whose elects are a protocol type), but those references aren’t stored on the stack, they’re stored within the array’s heap allocated buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are a `struct`, therefore a value type. However, there are some copy-on-write optimizations, which may be the reason for this `refCount`.

In the [documentation for Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), it states:

> Arrays, like all variable-size collections in the standard library, use copy-on-write optimization. Multiple copies of an array share the same storage until you modify one of the copies. When that happens, the array being modified replaces its storage with a uniquely owned copy of itself, which is then modified in place. Optimizations are sometimes applied that can reduce the amount of copying.

It also gives an example:

> In the example below, a numbers array is created along with two copies that share the same storage. When the original numbers array is modified, it makes a unique copy of its storage before making the modification. Further modifications to numbers are made in place, while the two copies continue to share the original storage.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> var firstCopy = numbers
> var secondCopy = numbers
>
> // The storage for 'numbers' is copied here
> numbers[0] = 100
> numbers[1] = 200
> numbers[2] = 300
> // 'numbers' is [100, 200, 300, 4, 5]
> // 'firstCopy' and 'secondCopy' are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```

So before the array is mutated, the storage of the array is shared. This is why it needs to count the references, to not deallocate an array which still may be in use by another variable.

Comment: @MartinR I’m pointing `refCount` next to `d[0]` not `Line`or `Point`

Comment: @PrepareFor: Yes, I had already noticed that and deleted the comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MartinR oh! i didn’t know that. thanks too